# Add number to end of div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to create a simple addClass on hover. Hovering over a `#science-panel-number` div triggers a class of `.active` to be added to an `#iphone-screen-number` div.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('#science-panel-1').hover(function(){
    $('#iphone-screen-1').addClass('active');
},function(){
    $('#iphone-screen-1').removeClass('active');
});

$('#science-panel-2').hover(function(){
    $('#iphone-screen-2').addClass('active');
},function(){
    $('#iphone-screen-2').removeClass('active');
});

$('#science-panel-3').hover(function(){
    $('#iphone-screen-3').addClass('active');
},function(){
    $('#iphone-screen-3').removeClass('active');
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div id="science-panel-1" class="science-panel__item">
            Content goes in here!
    </div>
    <div id="science-panel-2" class="science-panel__item">
        Content goes in here!
    </div>
    <div id="science-panel-3" class="science-panel__item">
        Content goes in here!
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    div id="iphone-screen-1" class="iphone-screen-item">
        <img src="IMG-url-here.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    div id="iphone-screen-2" class="iphone-screen-item">
        <img src="IMG-url-here.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="iphone-screen-3" class="iphone-screen-item">
        <img src="IMG-url-here.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="iphone-screen-4" class="iphone-screen-item">
        <img src="IMG-url-here.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="iphone-screen-5" class="iphone-screen-item">
        <img src="IMG-url-here.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="iphone-screen-6" class="iphone-screen-item">
        <img src="IMG-url-here.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="science-panel-4" class="science-panel__item">
        Content goes in here!
    </div>
    <div id="science-panel-5" class="science-panel__item">
        Content goes in here!
    </div>
    <div id="science-panel-6" class="science-panel__item">
        Content goes in here!
    </div>
</div>
```

This feels like a lot of code to do the same script. Is there a way to have one piece of script that can add the numbers it self? As `#science-panel-1` will always link to to `#iphone-screen-1` and so on.

Comment: Can you please share your HTMl as well so that it will more help ful to find out elements

Comment: Yes sorry, HTML added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do what you need.  Just apply the handlers to elements whose ID begins with `science-panel-`, which should cover all of them...

```
$("[id^=science-panel-]").hover(function() {
    // get the corresponding iphone-screen element id
    var iphoneScreen = "#" + this.id.replace("science-panel-", "iphone-screen-");
    $(iphoneScreen).addClass("active");
},function() {
    var iphoneScreen = "#" + this.id.replace("science-panel-", "iphone-screen-");
    $(iphoneScreen).removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend changing the markup to include the data you need to drive the script:

```
<div data-target="#iphone-screen-1" id="science-panel-1" class="science-panel__item">...</div>
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This allows you to select all the science panel items at once:

```
$('.science-panel__item')
```

and perform the exact same script on each of them:

```
$('.science-panel__item').hover(function () {
    $($(this).data('target')).addClass('active');
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// use the data-target attribute as a selector
}, function () {
    $($(this).data('target')).removeClass('active');
});
```

---

If you change the attribute and the selector, you'll have a reusable feature you can apply to *any* element:

```
$('[data-hover-target]').hover(function () {
    $($(this).data('hoverTarget')).addClass('active');
}, function () {
    $($(this).data('hoverTarget')).removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd firstly ask if the `active` class is strictly necessary? Can what you want be achieved with CSS if it is for styling only by using the `:hover` pseudoclass?

If you do need the `.active` class for some reason, I would change the markup to be a little more generic so that all the science panels had a CSS class of `.science-panel` and all the iphone screens had a class of `.iphone-screen`. Then you could simplify the JS to look like

```
$('.science-panel').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.iphone-screen').toggleClass('active', e.type === 'mouseenter');
});
```

This will find the `.iphone-screen` inside of the `.science-panel` that you hover over and toggle the class to on if the mouse enters and off when the mouse leaves it.

*edit: I see you've updated your answer to include your markup, this answer was assuming that your iphone-screens were nested in the science-panels so this won't necessarily work for you if you don't/can't nest your markup*